# CodeBlock c++ problem: Procces returned 126 (0x7E)

Tags: c++, code-blocks

I'm having a problem with CodeBlocks.

I can't run any C++ code and every time i try, I get the following error in terminal

```
Process returned 126 (0x7E)`
```

I googled it and found this link: http://www.thestudentroom.co.uk/showthread.php?t=1737736

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

- find the line which says NTFS somewhere on it.
- find the part of this line which says "user"- it's under the  header
- change "user" to "user,exec"- remove any "noexec"s
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd> and save when asked

But when i followed the first steps, fstab didn't appear so I can't follow the next steps required to fix the problem.

How can I fix this problem in a simplest way? How should i open fstab that is required?

Screenshots:
[image: http://s822.photobucket.com/user/mukunda13/media/fstab_zps0fe91c4e.png.html]

Answer (score 0):

since there's some time since you posted this question, you probably already found a solution, but since no one said anything about it, I'll leave this comment to help anyone who come across this problem. You should use gedit instead of nano (gedit is the default text editor for ubuntu), and this solution will only work if you use dual boot, and are trying to save/execute your code on the ntfs partition.
I'm having the same problem, but I dont have dual boot, no NTFS, my fstab have nothing of the stated stuff. =/